Unclear evaluation of brackets in $\lambda$-Calculus
I have problems with evaluating this $\lambda$-Expression.
$$(\lambda x.\lambda y.x(yx))\ (\lambda z.w)$$
The result should be, according to online calculators, $\lambda y.w$. But Iam really confused. There is no rule, which should indicate, that $x(yx)$ is equal to $x\ (yx)$. The expression
$$(\lambda x.\lambda y.x\ (yx))\ (\lambda z.w)$$
is indeed equivalent to $\lambda y.w$, but I only can do the following:
$$(\lambda x.\lambda y.x(yx))\ (\lambda z.w) = (\lambda y.(\lambda z.w(y\lambda z.w)))$$
I think, my biggest problem is, that I don't know, when Iam allowed to leave out spaces. According to wikipedia, $x\ y\ z$ can be written as $xyz$, if $x,y,z$ are single letter variables. However, $(yx)$ is not a single letter variable, so one cannot assume $x(yx) = x\ (yx)$.

You're definitely not allowed to leave out the space in "Iam". Joke aside, there are no spaces in the formal grammar of the $\lambda$-calculus, so why do you think it would make a difference? Both $x(yx)$ and $x\ (yx)$ denote the application of the variable $x$ to the application of the variable $y$ to the variable $x$.

In our lecture application was strictly defined with a space in it and every other task or example was consistent with that definition. Guess we were fooled...

First, to answer your question about the spaces: You should assume that all variables are single letters.  $(yx)$ means the same as $(y\;x)$: the value of $y$ is being applied to the value of $x$.  It is extremely unusual for $\lambda$-calculus variable names to be more than one letter long.
Now I'm going to present the proof that your expression is equivalent to $(\lambda y. w)$ and give the reasons.
$$(\lambda {x}.\lambda y.x(yx))\ {(\lambda z.w)}$$
To apply $(\lambda {x}.\lambda y.x(yx))$ to $(\lambda z.w)$,  replace each ${x}$  in $(\lambda y.{x}(y{x}))$ with $(\lambda z.w)$, giving:
$$(\lambda y.\overbrace{(\lambda {z}.w)}^x{(y\overbrace{(\lambda z.w)}^x)})$$
Now we are going to reduce the body of the $\lambda y.\cdots$ expression.  The $\lambda y.$ on the front will be unaffected.
The body has $(\lambda z.w)$ applied to $(y(\lambda z.w))$.  To reduce this application, we take the body of $\lambda z.w$, which is $w$, and we replace each $z$ with $(y(\lambda z.w))$.  There is no $z$, so the result is just $w$:
$$\lambda y.w$$
If this doesn't help, please leave a comment.

In our lecture it was stated, that for application we need a space, so I was really confused, because the terms I saw have sometimes spaces and sometimes don't. My lecture was at this point always consitent with adding a space before application. Thanks for clarifying, that spaces are not necessary.
